# Expo start throws error: package.json does not exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Am new to React native.
I just installed and initialized my first expo project.
But after running

expo start

> > 

I keep getting this error.
The expected package.json path(my project path)/package.json does not exist.

I have reinstalled several times, and tried every possible way I can.

Comment: Do you use it together with docker ?

Comment: @Tural Rzaxanov No I don't, must I run it with docker...am running on windows. I couldn't understand the reason for the error

Comment: Maybe, your terminal path is different by real project path. For example if you run npm start in terminal before this check current path. For look current terminal location enter this command: echo "Current Location is %cd%"

Comment: After it check screen information -> project path is same with opened terminal current path .

Comment: @TuralRzaxanov Since yesterday I couldn't understand much of your explanation, though I echo current location and it returns Current location is %cd%...and continues to show that same error.